# Batch registering all implementations of a generic interface with Ninject

Tags: .net, ninject, ioc-container, ninject.web.mvc

i have the following interfaces injected in Castle Windsor.  how do i do the same in Ninject?

```
container.Register(
    AllTypes.FromAssemblyNamed("Apps.Web")
        .BasedOn(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
        .WithService.FirstInterface());
```

i've tried:

```
this.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("Apps.Web.dll")
     .Select(y => y.Namespace.EndsWith("Handlers"))
     .BindSingleInterface());
```

but getting Object reference not set to an instance of an object error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use Ninject's [convention binding extensons](https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions) (install it from [NuGet](http://nuget.org/packages/ninject.extensions.conventions)) to do this.

Something like the following should work

```cs
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromAssembliesMatching("Apps.Web")
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .InheritedFrom(typeof(ICommandHandler<>))
    .BindSingleInterface());
```

I'm not 100% sure about the `FromAssembliesMatching` pattern, but you should be able to tweak that to pick up your assembly.

Comment: that worked.  i can see the bindings of kernel.GetModules().  but i can't see it in kernel.GetAll<ICommandHandler<MyCommand>>()?

Comment: I tried the same, but with `FromThisAssembly` and the `GetAll<ICommandHandler<MyCommand>>()` works perfectly... Wierd.

Comment: that was actually working.  i had to change my ServiceLocator :(  thanks for you help.